# protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter doesn't create html report

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, protractor, protractor-net

I have the following configuration in protractor config.js, but it is generating only the screenshots in the specified folder not the HTML report.

I have gone through the steps followed here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter'); 

onPrepare() {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './test/reports/',
            fileName: 'MyReportName'
        }));
  }
```

Can someone specify where I'm missing or is there any version specific issue?

I'm using 
**Protractor Version 5.2.0**, 
**Node v6.11.2**

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in this, the above code worked fine. It generated both screenshots and HTML report. Can you post the complete config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have issues with spec file which is causing the html report generation.

If we didn't provide `expect` and finish the `it` function, html report is not generating.

Always `expect` is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I'm using protractor-html-reporter, provides pie charts also and is way better than protractor jasmine2html reporter.